# How to make TLayout invisible in design time in delphi firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am building a simple application which consists of many TLayouts components. I have to make one of the TLayouts invisible so that I can work on other TLayout.

Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to make one of the TLayouts invisible so that I can work on
>   other TLayout.

To hide a `TLayout` at **Runtime**, simply set its [Visible](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Layouts.TLayout.Visible) property to False.

To make it Visible again, set the same property to True.

To hide a `TLayout` at **DesignTime**, simply set its [DesignVisible](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Layouts.TLayout.DesignVisible) property to False.